# how do i scroll to the bottom of the textbox useing EM_SETSCROLLPOS in SendMessage?

Tags: c++, c, textbox, scrollbar, richedit

I tried this:

```
tagPOINT mypoint;
    mypoint.x=0;
    mypoint.y = (17 * (tmsgcount - 16)) + 5;
SendMessage(hwnd,EM_SETSCROLLPOS,0,(LPARAM)&mypoint);
```

i was trying to calculate the height i should scroll down to get to the bottom of the scroll bar with the point. But this only work when i have the same font type size and screen resolution and does not seem like the proper solution.

if i new how i could get the height of the text in the text box i could use that, or  if there is some already defined value for a scroll to bottom value? I can find so little examples online. any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send EM_LINESCROLL to scroll to the last line.

Comment: actually since i was already keeping track of the lines in my box i was able to implement this to work